# Unlimited values field in Drupal 7 - how to show extra field in page.tpl.php

Tags: theming

I know how can I retrieve the first file name

```
$fileupload = $node->field_fileupload[$node->language][0]['filename'];
```

but how can I retrieve the other unlimited file names

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to run a foreach:

```
foreach($node->field_fileupload[$node->language] as $fileupload) {
  echo $fileupload['filename'];
}
```